# How Qcombobox change text of a line edit

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

In a user setting page, in that window i want a combobox that once you have selected something it will change the text of a line edit. for example
someone chose patrick and than the text change to his address and phone number.

im suspecting the code will look something like this:

```
if Qcombobox == "patrick"{
QlineEdit_phone = "911"
}
```

i have started to use QT designer and im lost on how Iam connecting slot and signal with object also.

Comment: Use signals and slots.  Depending on how you design your program you may want to use QComboBox::itemData to store the extra data in the QComboBox item itself.

Comment: Your answer has been deleted because if it is not an answer, it is only a comment indicating that you have found an answer and that does not help the community, then you added a link that does not help either since if the link is broken then it will be unusable. I recommend you read [ask], [answer] and indicate an answer explaining your solution and if it is possible to add the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the slot to change the editline by the change of selection through a combobox look like:

```
void pagesetting::on_comboBox_activated(const QString &arg1)
    {
        if (arg1=="gmail"){
           ui-> lineEdit_port -> setText("465");
           ui -> lineEdit_host -> setText("smtp.gmail.com");
        }

        if (arg1=="yahoo"){
           ui-> lineEdit_port -> setText("465");
           ui -> lineEdit_host -> setText("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
        }
    }
```

if you use qt designer you still need to delcare everything if you want to play with the object